# Unable to create a constructor in C++ class

Tags: c++, class, constructor, compiler-errors, declaration

I am trying to create a class in C++ (I have not worked with classes in a long time!) and I am trying to create a few constructors in the following way:

```
#ifndef TAAP_HEAD
#define TAAP_HEAD

class TaaP
{
public:
  // default cosntructor
  Taap();

  // constructor with xyz
  Taap(double xyz[3]);

private:
  double m_xyz[3];
  double m_Rho;
  double m_GradRho[3];
  double m_HessRho[3][3];
  double m_EigenValues[3];
  double m_EigenVectors[3][3];
};
#endif
```

where `Taap()` will simply assign `xyz` to `{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}`, but `Taap(double xyz[3])` will allow the user to input their own starting coordinate.

The error I get upon compilation is :

```
hdr_taap.h:9:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Taap’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   Taap();
        ^
hdr_taap.h:12:21: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Taap’ with no type [-fpermissive]
   Taap(double xyz[3]);
                     ^
```

Does this make any sense? I have tried to follow a lot of examples of class construction and cannot see anything I am doing wrong.

Comment: Typos: you need `TaaP`, not `Taap`, or vice-versa. The constructors must have the same name as the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive. Change TaaP to Taap

Comment: Thanks! I'm coming from fortran so I am not used to worrying about that stuff!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that the class is named `TaaP` and your constructors are named `Taap` (note the capitalisation). Constructors should have exactly the same name as the class they belong to.